# Extended NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uitableview, nstableview

I would like to make a table-view with expanding ability.
When you press a row, the row should expand to show options like delete, copy and so on.
I have found an example for iOS, but I didn't get it running on Mac OS X, because `NSTableView` and `UITableView` are very different.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kofiles

Has anyone another template?
Or maybe even get this example running on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have code to hand you but you can use a view-based NSTableView. Your prototype view can resize itself to include controls if it's selected. All that's a bit complex to condense into a reasonably brief answer but if you use a view-based table view and treat the prototype view like any other that would grow and show extra controls, then wire this behavior to the selection state, it should work.

Note: you *will* have to write some code for the expansion portion, to handle resizing it, showing the controls, and notifying the table view that one of its rows changed height. Lots of documentation and examples exist out there for each individual component of your problem. Post more specific questions as you run into roadblocks.

Comment: I know what you mean, I'd implement a subclass of NSTableCellView and make a delegate to the controller to resize the row, but how do I do that properly. 
So, how do I animate the table row height?

Comment: **Please read the documentation** and post a **separate question** about **what you've tried** and **what's not working**. When you call the -noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:, it should automagically animate the sizing for you. It says, "For View-based tables, this method will animate."

Comment: As to the view itself, use -setFrame: or -setFrameSize:  via [[view animator] setFrame:someNewFrame]; to resize based on the needed height for the extra controls (or the lack thereof). Use NSAnimationContext grouping to group the frame size change together with notifying the table view and it should give you a smooth animation where the table is growing the row while the row's view is growing.